# How do I provide a value to this data type Option<[u8; 3]> in rust?

Tags: rust

I need to call a function with a parameter with the type of **Option<[u8; 3]>**. I'm supposed to pass a number to this function but I don't know how. The editor suggest type [u8; 3] is an enum, but doesn't look like one to me.

I tried to pass Some(35) as the argument to it but failed.

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).  The syntax of array types is covered in there.

Comment: That is an array: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html It wants three numbers. `Option` is an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[u8; 3]` is an array type with 3 elements and the type of each is `u8`. The function accepts 3 numbers instead of 1.

A possible solution is:

```rust
the_function(Some([35, 0, 0]));
```

You should read the documentation of the function to figure out the right way to use.